# Property does not exist in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, types, maps

I'm trying to render information from the "rest countries" api through a map, but my typescript doesn't recognize the type inside my array with the information.

```
errors : "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'."
         "Property 'population' does not exist on type 'never'."
         "Property 'region' does not exist on type 'never'."
         "Property 'flags' does not exist on type 'never'."
```

```
import * as C from './styles';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Input from '../../components/Input';

import { api } from '../../api';

import { CountriesTS } from '../../types/Countries';
import CountryItem from '../../components/CountryItem';

const Countries = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCountries()
  }, [])

  const getAllCountries = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const resultCountries = await api.getCountries();
    setCountries(resultCountries);
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(countries);
  }

  return (
    <C.CountriesArea>
      <Input />
      <div className="countries">
        {loading &&
          <div className=''>Carregando...</div>
        }
        {!loading &&
          countries.map((item) => (
            <CountryItem 
              name={item.name}
              population={item.population}
              region={item.region}
              capital={item.capital}
              flag={item.flags.png}
            />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </C.CountriesArea>
  )
}

export default Countries
```

CountryItem folder:

```
import { CountryItemTS } from '../../types/CountryItem';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const CountryItem = ({name, population, region, capital, flag}: CountryItemTS) => {
  return (
    <C.CountryItem>
      <Link to={`country/${name}`}>
        <div className="img--area">
          <img src={flag} alt={`Bandeira do País: ${name}`} />
        </div>
        <div className="data--area">
          <p className="country--name">{name}</p>
          <p>Population: <span>{population}</span></p>
          <p>Region: <span>{region}</span></p>
          <p>Capital: <span>{capital}</span></p>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </C.CountryItem>
  )
}

export default CountryItem
```

API folder:

```
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/'
})

export const api = {
    getCountries: async () => {
        let response = await http.get('/all')
        return response.data
    },
    getCountry: async (name: string) => {
        let response = await http.get(`/name/${name}?fullText=true`)
        return response.data
    },
    getCountryByCode: async (code: string) => {
        let response = await http.get(`/alpha?codes=${code}`)
        return response.data
    }

}
```

Type CountryItemTS folder:

```
export interface CountryItemTS {
    name: string,
    capital: string,
    population: number,
    region: string,
    flag: string,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're initiating `countries` with an empty array, TypeScript don't know which type it is. Do the following to give `countries` a type.

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState<CountryItemTS[]>([]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me, but now I have another error. After the "loading" finishes, my screen is completely white and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

In "Countries" component , the initializing of countries state should be with type like this

`const [countries, setCountries] = useState<CountryItemTS[]>([]);`

If the keys received in `countries` state are different as I can notice in line `flag={item.flags.png}`,

then you can declare a new interface like this:-

```
interface ICountries extends CountryItemTS{
       flags: { png: string };
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. This solved my main problem, but now i am also dealing with another problem, after the "loading" finishes, my screen is completely white and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Can you provide the object that you are getting in `resultCountries ` ?